# How to fill page width of tables with css

Tags: css

I have a table separated and formated using the CSS. I am trying to get the whole table to align the same width. I would like specifically for black 2 out of the 5 in the row to fill the width so each of the three table are the same width.

[image]

Comment: You can try to set a style on all your tables **style="width:100%"** if you wanted them to go 100% of the parent container

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend you to use

The `<table width="100%"></table>`  attribute for the table tag.

Comment: Ended up adding the width atribute in the div's in the CSS, thanks for the pointer.